# Typescript - Generic type extending itself

Tags: typescript, generics

I recently came across something that looked like this:

```
interface Test<T extends Test<T>> {
  a: number;
  b: T;
}

function foo <T extends Test<T>>(el: T): T {
  ...
}
```

I have to say I am a bit perplexed as to what exactly this is, and why something like this would be required. I've been through the [Generics section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) of the Typescript handbook but couldn't find anything similar.

What does that interface achieve that can't be done with something like the following?

```
interface Test<T>
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Without the actual example, I can only speak in generalities.  That sort of syntax is what you need in a language like Java that doesn't have [polymorphic `this` types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types), which I'll get to shortly.

---

The idea is that you want a generic type that refers to other objects of the *same type* as its containing class or interface. Let's look at your `Test` interface:

```
interface Test<T extends Test<T>> {
  a: number;
  b: T;
}
```

This describes a linked-list-like structure where the `b` property of a `Test<T>` must also be a `Test<T>`, since `T` extends `Test<T>`.  But additionally, it must be (a subtype of) the *same type* as the parent object.  Here's an example of two implementations:

```
interface ChocolateTest extends Test<ChocolateTest> {
  flavor: "chocolate";
}
const choc = {a: 0, b: {a: 1, flavor: "chocolate"}, flavor: "chocolate"} as ChocolateTest;
choc.b.b = choc;

interface VanillaTest extends Test<VanillaTest> {
  flavor: "vanilla";
}
const vani = {a: 0, b: {a: 1, flavor: "vanilla"}, flavor: "vanilla"} as VanillaTest;
vani.b.b = vani;
```

Both `ChocolateTest` and `VanillaTest` are implementations of `Test`, but they are not interchangable.  The `b` property of a `ChocolateTest` is a `ChocolateTest`, while the `b` property of a `VanillaTest` is a `VanillaTest`.  So the following error occurs, which is desirable:

```
choc.b = vani; // error!
```

Now you know when you have a `ChocolateTest` that the entire list is full of other `ChocolateTest` instances without worrying about some other `Test` showing up:

```
choc.b.b.b.b.b.b.b.b.b // <-- still a ChocolateTest
```

---

Compare this behavior to the following interface:

```
interface RelaxedTest {
  a: number;
  b: RelaxedTest;
}

interface RelaxedChocolateTest extends RelaxedTest {
  flavor: "chocolate";
}
const relaxedChoc: RelaxedChocolateTest = choc;

interface RelaxedVanillaTest extends RelaxedTest {
  flavor: "vanilla";
}
const relaxedVani: RelaxedVanillaTest = vani;
```

You can see that `RelaxedTest` doesn't constrain the `b` property to be the *same* type as the parent, just to some implementation of `RelaxedTest`.  So far, it looks the same, but the following behavior is different:

```
relaxedChoc.b = relaxedVani; // no error
```

This is allowed because `relaxedChoc.b` is of type `RelaxedTest`, which `relaxedVani` is compatible with.  Whereas `choc.b` is of type `Test<ChocolateTest>`, which `vani` is *not* compatible with.

---

That ability of a type to constrain another type to be the *same as the original type* is useful.  It's so useful, in fact, that TypeScript has something called [polymorphic `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) for just this purpose.  You can use `this` as a type to mean "the same type as the containing class/interface", and do away with the generic stuff above:

```
interface BetterTest {
  a: number;
  b: this; // <-- same as the implementing subtype
}

interface BetterChocolateTest extends BetterTest {
  flavor: "chocolate";
}
const betterChoc: BetterChocolateTest = choc;

interface BetterVanillaTest extends BetterTest {
  flavor: "vanilla";
}
const betterVani: BetterVanillaTest = vani;

betterChoc.b = betterVani; // error!
```

This acts nearly the same as the original `Test<T extends Test<T>>` without the [possibly mind-bending circularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouroboros).  So, yeah, I'd recommend using polymorphic `this` instead, unless you have some compelling reason to do it the other way.

Since you said you came across this code, I wonder if it was some code from before the introduction of polymorphic `this`, or by someone who didn't know about it, or if there is some compelling reason I don't know about. Not sure.

---

Hope that makes sense and helps you.  Good luck!

Comment: What an answer! Need to take some time to go through it

Answer (score 2):

```
public static foo<TType extends number | string, T extends Tree<TType>>(data: T[]): T[] {
    console.log(data[0].key);
    return
}


export interface Tree<T> {
    label?: string;
    data?: any;
    parent?: Tree<T>;
    parentId?: T;
    key?: T;
}
```