# Class with property, where the property itself contains a property of type <T extends Class>

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm writing a `Engine` class that takes a map of `Module` classes on construction and instantiates them passing itself. The created instances are then stored in `modules`. I use generics to make sure the modules that exist on the engine are known and can be declared expected by functions that take an argument of type `Engine`.

This `Engine` class also holds map event handlers, which expect a callback that takes the `Engine` instance as their first argument. The handlers can be registered via a public method.

A module might look like this:

```
class Renderer extends Module<{Renderer: Renderer}> {
    constructor(engine: Engine<{Renderer: Renderer}>) {
        super(engine);

        this.engine.addEventHandler('draw', drawSomething);
    }

    renderText(message: string) {
        console.log(message);
    }
}
```

... where `drawSomething`, the event handler, would look like this:

```
function drawSomething(engine: Engine<{Renderer: Renderer}>): void {
    engine.modules.Renderer.renderText('hello world');
}
```

You can find the entire problem worked out [here in TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-DCXYOySCQ2CVUBQwo8yWaw2G3uBTIvpo4ZoR4x7g-HnQSBIm6ZgbF0uY2N+P6+oKhCK5-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), with the error at line 54. I've also created one with [only the type definitions](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIgOaggHgCoCyA9gCYCuANhAM7IQAekIJtx5VtAvMgN4C+APl4AoZGOQBbUpRoAuZIWkcA3KPEQAbhHAAJOMypRq8nmvHiA2pu1gAcnAkR51MFFAYAuvNRbd+kob4bDLUAhYequZ8qmbIIBAA7sgAFFLscsgAwkQgLlBkCGBwAEZUwRxBSjQCAJTemNiV6aGR4nAkJD42egbQySAOTsh57gA0yAAW-obevmA9AdBNIbXyGkTAJKp8wsJgAJ4ADihdfr1QyxwA8jDoWPF0jNosyOU0yNz8QtzJsdr3Qzu2FGsQAdOC4FAMMZkPp9uFhDUPkJ1psYsJQJBYIgUG9aKZzBY0jJ7I5nK53F5XlVtrtMdB4EhqelLjQbkCHgwmC88R9eIIROZ-th6gDWdR2Q14gIYuZ4klksL4qLGopmpKAatmTJxRrsDLhDsMeAGTisjk8gUiqVcHhMhQ4NRQoLxPKUuDQZDofI4eE6gp7Y7qLS9kcUNlcq4rSUylVqOLHtzWHHvi6xBY3qSUKBkABrCD7IgwBR4qkRy2FGO2vEZqpZjwCQ27YRAA), to see the shape of the concept I'm going for.

The problem I encounter is that when I register the event handler `drawSomething`, the generics I passed seem to be forgotten when checking if the handler is correctly typed. It is assumed the handler will be called without `Renderer` as a known module. Typescript tells me:

> Type 'Engine<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Engine<{ Renderer: Renderer; }>'

How do I make sure TypeScript knows that when I *register* an event handler to an `Engine` instance with certain modules, the handler will also be *passed* that same `Engine` instance with those modules when it's called?

I'm using TypeScript 3.5.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key issue is the recursive type definition of `Module`, which accepts another type that must be a subtype of itself.

### Original Code

```
class Module<TModulesOfEngine extends Modules = {}> {
    engine: Engine<TModulesOfEngine>;

    constructor(engine: Engine<TModulesOfEngine>) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }
}

class Engine<TModules extends Modules = {}> {
    public modules: TModules;
    public eventHandlers: {
        [eventName: string]: EventHandler<TModules>[];
    } = {};

    constructor(modules: ConstructableModules<TModules> = {} as ConstructableModules<TModules>) {
        this.modules = Object.keys(modules).reduce((allModules: TModules, moduleName: string): TModules => {
            const ModuleClass = modules[moduleName];
            return {
                ...allModules,
                [moduleName]: new ModuleClass(this),
            }
        }, {} as TModules);
    }
...
```

In some cases, the [polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) could be used, as shown in this example: [Typescript - Generic type extending itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50277451/1164465)

However, the `this` type cannot be used in static methods or constructors, which means that the following is an error.

```
class Module {
    engine: Engine<this>;

    // Error: A 'this' type is available only in a non-static member of a class or interface.
    constructor(engine: Engine<this>) { 
        this.engine = engine;
    }
}
```

Although it is not aesthetically pleasing, the following recursive type definition works.

## Solution

```
class Module<T extends Module<T>> {
    engine: Engine<T>;

    constructor(engine: Engine<T>) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }
}

class Engine<T extends Module<T>> {
    public modules: ModuleMap<T>;
    public eventHandlers: {
       [eventName: string]: EventHandler<T>[];
    } = {};

    constructor(modules: ConstructableModule<ModuleMap<T>>) {
        this.modules = Object.keys(modules).reduce((allModules: ModuleMap<T>, moduleName: string): ModuleMap<T> => {
            const ModuleClass = modules[moduleName];
            return {
                ...allModules,
                [moduleName]: new ModuleClass(this),
            }
        }, {} as ModuleMap<T>);
    }

    addEventHandler(name: string, handler: EventHandler<T>): void {
        this.eventHandlers = {
            ...this.eventHandlers,
            [name]: [
                ...(this.eventHandlers[name] || []),
                handler,
            ],
        };
    }
}
```

See working example on [Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gEwK4BsIwIZgDwBUoQAewEAdggM6yKoR4B89UAvFAN5QDaAtjWgHIZuEAFxQKwAE4BLUgHMAumPwBfANwAoDQGMUGClXjI0eAsTKVqxurkbsNURwXmzRUAKIvSN+podPtOFIJSSRtYDhJAAoyOVcxTzjvBgBKeycMqGAAC2kKADpY1xZnJIhNDJUNKo1ZEkkAMwxtaABhIJCw4AwAIxNcVr0DJjZ-R28Adygo-NmMSTkKMQxSEE4FFOVB-QpNGtBIKHbgqS7etCNabEuLrCZWUYzOG4hBYShZKABrCBA4BqstEwYCURw6p3C5zoL2Bzz4ryEEAU9GqWgO0HcADcyMAABIrBBoSSmIgkciGeEMe7TIreBJeHwAGigs3y80Wy1W6zSzCYmLg0gQfl0Ow8DJJ5nJgP6dkeTjASD60m0UF41iW0vQWAYFXlipQyoI2NIeIJRI1csynAgxuAbzcIVkigStvx5CJDHWuscKhKbHUWgygROoXCkSiatoGuOnUhfXQlJh2ts9DSlsyOTy+UjaCorAA8j0AFYQcL5H4gCgR+EUFL5SQQZAtKJRDAoFAvDVJnC2Zk5hHCMSO+SbTXAhgsEZjTJB8Ga7YGEr9ig8eH2hTemdOBvAJCSUjpLdH1ltjs1xnTo9PfvrsSTedDKuZ2sXq9OKpHlTM-1QfRj5OppuNQZBgCAIFiOJuoSEDRKQiJDlITrMtkZowS6kGocStijvygqHjOz6FK6mF5vhV6soRNoYe6MEUK+b5cHBwigpwl4MayUSUcRNGSCuTFIlAAA+glcBs9EMU4KE8eJV4KDJlRAaiOiPlAABKFgwTBZhkpYLzYOp5CaZIU6ziGXThrSbiJK4+kaQ2xlpmxjgUEgkDRJZKR+EelEMmyYEQSaUFElEADkCCSBgEwhcy4WRQAynAwiZiOinTg2hmSLgpIRhABgYHIDqISOZGmRQcBoPkKBwHIOV5QVnnTlUNQNEgpDhNIQRQLFEwJUluTyDEDL0mUtkZTBqZiLhCBkYNZTZjWnAAEQGQgRmLQov5UCtRl1ulq2ZdlIXZBA7ZwFAEyRCgCAhQ1NRoMAqogNZ3glPez0QFEbDLXZMGLWI232SoDXcE9vnLktAO-Qo9Z2VlxChbiJ1Vedl3XQ1WgaEAA).

Comment: Ah, of course! So, generically, that would mean:

`type EventHandler<TModulesOfEngine extends Modules = {}> = (engine: Engine<TModulesOfEngine>, ...args: any[]) => void;`

... but now I have a few other problems when I'm trying to pass the generic: "Type '{ Renderer: Renderer; }' does not satisfy the constraint 'Modules'. Type 'Renderer' is not assignable to type 'Module<{}>'."

Comment: That can be a solution, but then I'd need to coerce `Engine` every time I use it expecting modules, rather than being use it after construction with its modules known. Your initial suggestion about the missing generic on `EventHandler` was hugely helpful to solve it completely though, because it showed me I wasn't passing the generic everywhere.

Comment: @bakkerjoeri See updated answer with support for generics and a working Typescript Playground example.

Comment: Great! Thank you for the thorough explanation and alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

The original definition of the `Modules` interface was breaking the generics chain. Any usage of it made TypeScript lose the previously defined typing of `Engine.modules`. Since it didn't accept any generic to pass to `Module`, there is no way to capture the expected modules on `Engine`:

```
class Module<TModulesOfEngine extends Modules = {}> {
    engine: Engine<TModulesOfEngine>;

    constructor(engine: Engine<TModulesOfEngine>) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }
}

// This is missing generic arguments, making it impossible to preserve typing.
interface Modules {
    [moduleName: string]: Module;
}
```

To fix this, `Modules` needs to start accepting `TModulesOfEngine` as well:

```
class Module<TModulesOfEngine extends Modules<TModulesOfEngine> = {}> {
    engine: Engine<TModulesOfEngine>;

    constructor(engine: Engine<TModulesOfEngine>) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }
}

interface Modules<TModulesOfEngine extends Modules<TModulesOfEngine> = {}> {
    [moduleName: string]: Module<TModulesOfEngine>;
}
```

The full implementation of this can be found in [this TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECyD2ATAriApgHgCoJeiA8gGYCiAdgOYCWZa0aAHgC5pmIy6poTaf7HlqtAHzQAvNADeAX1GSAUNCX1KNNAC5ogtbyRdCpVSIDc8xcuDwyEJgCdkwJvFsAKVkI1ajmHHv6GPYQBKKXNlZSYACyoIADp3NXEVD1Nw6Xl0+RoWWyIwYDo+bl08bgFvemZWdjg-Yt9Sg20RJJk5MOgAbQBbOoA5MG7PG1saCgBdTSKS-XLA00zstFz8ugBhKxGHJjAAI3RsNfAodvDaAHdoF1ibsFsKCE0wMgBPTvGgzSwjyAgFsyYLwADutNnZtnt0EUeA19JUWGwOHUYdDRBI2q0Op0igMhtAaNAANZoF7wIjQWH4SbQDbWcGOSE+aHY-qDNDjYQZAHAugkABurCYAAlnoh0LYZv5mnRGAiatDJWUAmo0VJZEkXB0ErRNNLFU1vMIADQdG6xO4PJ6vd7yEJiUR8+BURCmeSgX5eDz6+HVJGNfWqjEKcJA5D7KjAaC9RpfaGpZSh8ORtACsjC0Xix6hcLhTopwW44Z2MbU-mCkVscUB97xpTSVrSV3hSx0+yOZwuaP6TS0rYM-ZoBWU7iB+uQGlgts7AdD1EhYM5pRRGKxLv4JIEXYAKzQjlixJeEE7yKCsVsaBQBRcLjAIBA0NjyKNUdZQ00IzGnwp0PEp0XOZbGxalKH4oCSNduB6V92Vrf8lHPJhkFsMhszg-8zVve8nw6NDlCg0pC2pC5gK4UCj2XCAghNXC6xw5RpGfGRoHHYdKNgzJwjARBEDLNMKzFZYXDINl32LShn0iDNll1VN00rZYAy-R1nVQxcKPiWT+MzTEaOgM11PzPipNsCBqJozphKGalOjo3CzRcAzNOMiALLZcZoAAHw8roPjM3SlEk+TbD8tDxhCtJ2K5N1jhgAAlaplmWH1ERIg5JHithEtsTQMsQLL1QXJRAPpJxXG1Tw9XShLz2y6Bcvy4JVJzCBkBBMrvCCJt-wM7xzW43i5IE1wAHJEFsMBzmG58xomgBleAhmXShOo6DjlHPTLbCwWVO24CAwAoItRmWprm02eB0FiEB4AoXaoAOtAVrSKKiGQMhHCoKxoBm855sW6JKDcbxdW8DAqs26S6uq5ZZCUp1ECa8rV2RWJ6pqs9qu25gXGGyI0DveBoHOZwQEQYaVsydAmCjF5pSSYjKrRyGmdsWQXHBvKaukFazHkIA).

I found out by removing the type defaults (e.g. `TModules extends Modules = {}`) which revealed where passing the generic was forgotten.